# if condition in ng-repeat on a variable

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I get data in **angularjs** from sql query as:

```
{"orders":[
{
    "orderId":"1674","itemId":"468","SubTotal":"40.00","Total":"48.98","Status":"Printed","Title":"Mangled : Large","Quantity":"1","dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
},
{
    "orderId":"1674","itemId":"469","SubTotal":"40.00","Total":"48.98","Status":"Printed","Title":"Skull Collage : Large","Quantity":"1","dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
},
{
    "orderId":"1675","itemId":"33949","SubTotal":"40.00","Total":"48.98","Status":"Printed","Title":"Summerside \"The Saved\" EP CD -Red or Blue! : BLUE","Quantity":"1","dateCreated":"2009-06-03" 
},
{
    "orderId":"1674","itemId":"33954","SubTotal":"40.00","Total":"48.98","Status":"Printed","Title":"Summerside \"The Saved\" EP CD -Red or Blue! : RED","Quantity":"1","dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
}]}
```

now I want to find out how many records are having same ***orderId***, so that I could place them in same **section/div** and display it as 1 group.

I am using **ng-repeat** to display data.

```
<div ng-repeat="order in itemorders">
<div class="order-lis-box border-radius">
    <div class="up line overflow-hidden text">
        <div class="fl black mb10">Order No. <span>{{ order.orderId }}</span><br><span class="capitalize grey F14 bold">Rs. {{ order.Total }}</span></div>
        <div class="custom-datetime text-right">{{ order.dateCreated }}</div>
    </div>
    .
    .
    .
</div> <!-- order-lis-box -->
```

What should I add use so I could show the way I want?

Comment: I am using ng-table for something similar: http://ng-table.com/#/grouping/demo-grouping-fn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To accomplish something similar you can use [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter), and then use the GroupBy function.

After injecting anular-filter in your app, you will only need to

```
<div ng-repeat="(key,value) in orders | groupBy: 'orderId'">
    <div class="fl black mb10">Order No. <span>{{ key }}
    <div class="order-lis-box border-radius" ng-repeat="order in value">
    <div class="up line overflow-hidden text">
    </span><br><span class="capitalize grey F14 bold">Rs. {{ order.Total }}</span></div>
    <div class="custom-datetime text-right">{{ order.dateCreated }}</div>
</div>
.
.
.
</div>
```

here is a [plunker](http://jsbin.com/pebuqatuva/1/edit?html,js,output) with an example of your case.

Comment: yeah!! you are almost there, but how will i know that **orderId** has changed and need new div for new **orderId**!! and thankss :)

Comment: @Asmita I've updated my plunker, and the code, look if that works out better for you.

Comment: hey thats great!! :) Thanks a lot.. i am all new in angular... n it helping me out! I will be trying this, please keep track here, if I stuck! ;)

Comment: for new issues you should open new questions. if this solved you problem please consider accepting the answer

Comment: yes, I am just trying this n its regarding to same que! Surely acceptable!!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you create a `Javascript` function to change your `JSON` object to

```
{
    "orders":
    [
        {
            "orderId":"1674",
            "items" : 
            [
                {
                    "itemId":"468",
                    "SubTotal":"40.00",
                    "Total":"48.98",
                    "Status":"Printed",
                    "Title":"Mangled : Large",
                    "Quantity":"1",
                    "dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
                },
                {
                    "itemId":"469",
                    "SubTotal":"40.00",
                    "Total":"48.98",
                    "Status":"Printed",
                    "Title":"Skull Collage : Large",
                    "Quantity":"1",
                    "dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
                },
                {
                    "itemId":"33954",
                    "SubTotal":"40.00",
                    "Total":"48.98",
                    "Status":"Printed",
                    "Title":"Summerside \"The Saved\" EP CD -Red or Blue! : RED",
                    "Quantity":"1",
                    "dateCreated":"2009-06-03"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId":"1675",
            "items" : 
            [
                {
                    "itemId":"33949",
                    "SubTotal":"40.00",
                    "Total":"48.98",
                    "Status":"Printed",
                    "Title":"Summerside \"The Saved\" EP CD -Red or Blue! : BLUE",
                    "Quantity":"1",
                    "dateCreated":"2009-06-03" 
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and then it will be easier to manipulate on your `HTML` file

```
<div ng-repeat="order in itemorders">
<div class="order-lis-box border-radius">
    <div class="up line overflow-hidden text">
        <div class="fl black mb10">Order No. <span>{{ order.orderId }}</span><br><span class="capitalize grey F14 bold">Rs. {{ order.Total }}</span></div>
        <div class="custom-datetime text-right">{{ order.dateCreated }}</div>
    </div>
     <div class="up line overflow-hidden text" ng-repeat="item in order.items">
        <div class="fl black mb10">Item Id<span>{{ item.itemId }}</span><br></div>
        .
        .
        .
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can I do it using PHP? and will return data in same form to HTML. Nice 1.

Comment: Yes you can use PHP for that.

Comment: ok, thanks. it looks be feasible. can u help me out how can it be done?

Comment: Sure. Is it possible to have the PHP from where you bring the data ?

Comment: Seems complicated like that. I will try and let you know ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91585/discussion-between-asmita-and-abennouna).